# How do I retrieve value at a specific location with string split?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in table which has '!' seperated values of kind:

```
John Amber!New York!Manager
Lena Jackson!Cubec!Engineer
Otis Willey!Indiana!Salesman
```

I want to retrieve the first value before '!' for each record into another column 'Name'. i.e. I want to get names John Amber, Lena Jackson and Otis Willey in a column called 'Name'

How do I do the same in SQL Server.

Comment: By not using `STRING_SPLIT`; it doesn't preserve the ordinal positions of the values (unless you are using Azure SQL Database or SQL Server 2022+, in which case you can make use of the optional `ordinal` parameter/column). You'll want to use `CHARINDEX` and `LEFT` here. The better question, however, is why are you storing delimited data in your database in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
WITH SampleData as (
select 'John Amber!New York!Manager' as vals
union 
select 'Lena Jackson!Cubec!Engineer' as vals
UNION 
select 'Otis Willey!Indiana!Salesman' as vals
)
select 
LEFT(vals,CHARINDEX('!',vals)-1) as [Name],[vals]
from SampleData
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if I want to get New york ,cubec and Indiana?